In MobaXterm, can I change directory in terminal based on selection of directory in the Windows tree?
I know the "follow terminal folder" changes the directory in GUI (browsing pane), based on directory that I go to in the terminal. I would like to know if the reverse is possible, i.e, double-clicking on a directory in the GUI changes it in terminal as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I do not think it is possible unless you reverse engineer and patch mobaxterm, so no :).
